# Solr - ReplicationHandler - masterUrl error when defining it on core.properties for slave

Tags: solr, replication, solrconfig

I'm having some issues with adding some customization to *solrconfig.xml*, what I'm trying to do is set the **masterUrl** for the **ReplicationHandler** using the *core.properties* file. Funny thing is that if I manually paste the url on the solrconfig.xml it works like a charm. Am I missing some configuration on *core.properties*?

This are the files:

**solrconfig.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
      <lst name="slave">

          <str name="masterUrl">${master_host}</str>

          <!--Interval in which the slave should poll master .Format is HH:mm:ss . If this is absent slave does not poll automatically.
           But a fetchindex can be triggered from the admin or the http API -->
          <str name="pollInterval">00:00:10</str>
          <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
          <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>

       </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

**core.properties**

```
name=locations
master_host=http://master:8983/solr/locations-master/replication
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
slave_1   | 2020-01-23 20:20:23.821 WARN  (indexFetcher-20-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.h.IndexFetcher Master at: http://master:8983/solr/locations-master is not available. Index fetch failed by exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://master:8983/solr/locations-master: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
slave_1   | <head>
slave_1   | <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
slave_1   | <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
slave_1   | </head>
slave_1   | <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
slave_1   | <p>Problem accessing /solr/locations-master/replication. Reason:
slave_1   | <pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
slave_1   | </body>
slave_1   | </html>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Im running solar's solr:8.4.1-slim image

Answer (score 0):

In core.properties I was setting the name of the core to be locations when the name I set when creating it was locations-master. I deleted name=locations from core.properties and the it starting working :^)